# I have a syntax error in my Outer Apply statement, I can't understand why

Tags: google-bigquery, outer-apply

This is my code

```
SELECT
A.* ,
B.ID as CB_ID,

FROM 
    `TABLE_1` A

OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
    FROM `TABLE_2` B
WHERE A.business_ID = B.company_ID)
```

I'm getting this error

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword OUTER at [8:1]

and i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe standard sql utilizes APPLYs.  In this scenario you will have to switch to a `LEFT OUTER` join.

The documentation here outlines the query syntax in BigQuery:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: I actually used the LEFT JOIN with group by and i got the result i needed, thanks